# Connection object Error Number returned:-2147024770

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vbscript, tivoli

We are migrating our applications from Windows 2003 to 2008 application server. We have vbs script in a job which is invoked from Tivoli Workload Scheduler (Windows)/JOBLNCH 8.5.1. We are getting the error while creating ADODB object (Error Number returned:-2147024770). The error does not occur when we directly run the job on the 2008 server, but only when invoked throught the TWS scheduler. Also, this error is not occurring on 2003 server when run through the TWS.

Here is the code snippet used to create object.

set oSrcConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Could you please help us identify if any settings need to be changed to avoid this error.

Comment: what kind of OS? is it x86 or 64 ?
It depends...

Comment: The error number translates to 8007007e, you may have more luck searching for that.

Comment: C:\Users\David Candy>net helpmsg 126

The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps seem to have fixed the issue:

1) Provide the path of the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado in the jobmanc file of the TWS server.

2) Create a folder C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop (TWS uses this folder)